# scala : HBase : newAPIHadoopRDD doesn't work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

i'm trying to use the class newAPIHadoopRDD for reading from simple HBase table. 
Here the code exeuted

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin, Result}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat

val tableName = "t1"
val hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
hconf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "t1")

val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hconf, classOf[TableInputFormat], 
classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
println("records found : " + hBaseRDD.count())
```

The problem is that every action on the RDD (count in this case but it is the same with the collect for example), doesn't return any information about running error or success, simply hang out and seems to be in a loop.
Does anyone else have the same problem? Or know hot to fix it?

This is what i receive if i hit ctrl-C

```
scala> hBaseRDD.count
18/01/30 07:23:15 WARN repl.Signaling: Cancelling all active jobs, this can take a while. Press Ctrl+C again to exit now.
18/01/30 07:23:15 WARN spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: No stages are running, but numRunningTasks != 0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 0 cancelled as part of cancellation of all jobs
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1430)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobCancellation(DAGScheduler.scala:1370)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$doCancelAllJobs$1.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:716)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$doCancelAllJobs$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:716)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$doCancelAllJobs$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:716)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.doCancelAllJobs(DAGScheduler.scala:716)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1623)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1600)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:623)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1930)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1943)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1956)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1970)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
  ... 48 elided
```

Comment: What do see on spark UI? does it hang on the driver or the executors? did you try to dump the driver process and see where exactly it hangs?

Comment: @shay__  i've add the stack the returns me the shell. How can i see what you said in your answer?